# Apache Camel headers don't work in http query

Tags: java, http, apache-camel

I am trying to call an external API with an access token parameter in query, by taking it from header, however for some reason it doesn't work, API returns error `Access token not configured`.

But when I'm calling log on the same string, access token from header appears to be in place.

Code from configure method in my Route:

```java
from("direct:user_get")
        .log("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?access_token=${header.access_token}&v=5.131")
        .to("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?access_token=${header.access_token}&v=5.131");
```

Call of `FluentProducerTemplate` (Actual token replaced with "token_example"):

```java
String userGetResponse = producerTemplate
        .to("direct:user_get")
        .withHeader("access_token", "token_example")
        .request(String.class);
```

When I pass token right into the `.to()` call itself, everything works fine, API returns valid response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `toD` because it is a dynamic endpoint. So what are you sending is this string `${header.access_token}` and not the the header Token.

```
.toD("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?access_token=${header.access_token}&v=5.131");
```

Normnal to doesn't transform the uri only toD make this. Check the [Docs](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/eips/toD-eip.html)

> The to is used for sending messages to a static endpoint. In other
> words to sends message only to the same endpoint.
>
> The toD is used for sending message to a dynamic endpoint. The dynamic
> endpoint is evaluated on-demand by an Expression. By default, the
> Simple expression is used to compute the dynamic endpoint URI.